# How can I remove the second list from the output?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here's the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url_sca = "https://www.steakcookoffs.com/cookoffs?EventViewMode=1&EventListViewMode=1"
page_sca = requests.get(url_sca).text
doc_sca = BeautifulSoup(page_sca, features="lxml")

text_date = doc_sca.find(class_="eventInfoBoxValue").strong
dates = str(text_date).split(">")[-2].split("<")[0]

for page_sca in dates:
    url_sca = "https://www.steakcookoffs.com/cookoffs?EventViewMode=1&EventListViewMode=1"
    page_sca = requests.get(url_sca).text
    doc_sca = BeautifulSoup(page_sca, features="lxml")

    results_dates = doc_sca.find_all(class_=re.compile("eventInfoBoxValue"))
    for result in results_dates:
        print(str(result).split(">")[2].split("<"))
```

Output :

Friday, June 17, 2022
Delta, Pennsylvania
Friday, June 17, 2022
Searcy, Arkansas
Friday, June 17, 2022
Fort Worth, Texas
Saturday, June 18, 2022
Fort Worth, Texas
Saturday, June 18, 2022
Fort Worth, Texas
Saturday, June 18, 2022
Katy, Texas
Saturday, June 18, 2022
Searcy, Arkansas
Saturday, June 18, 2022
Searcy, Arkansas
Friday, June 24, 2022
Belvidere, Illinois
Friday, June 24, 2022
Folkston, Georgia
Friday, June 24, 2022
Church Hill, Tennessee
Friday, June 24, 2022
Church Hill, Tennessee
Saturday, June 25, 2022
Folkston, Georgia
Saturday, June 25, 2022
Johnson City, Tennessee
Saturday, June 25, 2022
Lexington, Michigan
37
Saturday, June 25, 2022
Buffalo, Missouri
Saturday, June 25, 2022
Folkston, Georgia
Saturday, June 25, 2022
Liberty, Texas
Saturday, June 25, 2022
Skowhegan, Maine
Saturday, June 25, 2022
Oxford, Mississippi
Saturday, June 25, 2022
Oxford, Mississippi
Saturday, June 25, 2022
Waynesville, Ohio
Sunday, June 26, 2022
Oxford, Mississippi
Friday, July 01, 2022
El Dorado, Arkansas
Friday, July 01, 2022
Shiner, Texas

Once I add `[0]` to the end of my last line of code it prints the first item from both lists. I just want the `date` to print and not the location.

Comment: Copy-pasting both codes from the two answers below, you'll get only the date printed. How those output differ from what you're looking for? Can you make a differentiation between your current output and your expected output inside your post?

Answer (score 1):

Please use find methode along with getText, your last couple of lines should be like this,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url_sca = "https://www.steakcookoffs.com/cookoffs?EventViewMode=1&EventListViewMode=1"
page_sca = requests.get(url_sca).text
doc_sca = BeautifulSoup(page_sca, features="lxml")

text_date = doc_sca.find(class_="eventInfoBoxValue").strong
dates = str(text_date).split(">")[-2].split("<")[0]

for page_sca in dates:
    url_sca = "https://www.steakcookoffs.com/cookoffs?EventViewMode=1&EventListViewMode=1"
    page_sca = requests.get(url_sca).text
    doc_sca = BeautifulSoup(page_sca, features="lxml")
    date = doc_sca.find("div", { "class" : "eventInfoBoxValue" }, "strong").getText()
    print(date)
```

Comment: Also, no need for the `for` loop, right?

Comment: Yes, no need of for loop

Comment: it just appears that I dont need the for loop because i only showed the first two lines of output.

Comment: using print(str(results_dates[0]).split(">")[2].split("<")[0]) just prints "Friday, June 17, 2022" repeatedly.

Comment: please keep the print statement out of for (first) loop indentation

Comment: CurrentOutput:
['Friday, June 17, 2022', '/strong']
['Delta, Pennsylvania', '/span']
['Friday, June 17, 2022', '/strong']

ExpectedOutput:
Friday, June 17, 2022 
Delta, Pennsylvania 
Friday, June 17, 2022

did I get it right??

Comment: No. this is why the second for loop is there because I am pulling more than one date and location.

Comment: Friday, June 17, 2022
Delta, Pennsylvania
Friday, June 17, 2022
Searcy, Arkansas
Friday, June 17, 2022
Fort Worth, Texas.      This is some of the current output. I am wanting to eliminate the locations and keep the dates

Comment: After reading through your comments, I edited the code with find and getText methods, please check it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeautifulSoup.find` instead of `BeautifulSoup.find_all` to just get the first match:

```
results_dates = doc_sca.find(class_=re.compile("eventInfoBoxValue"))
print(str(results_dates).split(">")[2].split("<"))
```